# print Arraylist without loop

Tags: java, arraylist, println

I want to print elements in my Arraylist without using a loop of any kind is that possible in java?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Person
{
    String name;
    String role;

    public Person(String name, String role)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person person1 = new Person("george","programmer");
        Person person2 = new Person("barack","programmer");
        Person person3 = new Person("ismail","programmer");

        ArrayList <Person> people = new ArrayList <Person>();
        people.add(person1);
        people.add(person2);
        people.add(person3);

        System.out.println(people.get(0));
        System.out.println(people.get(1));
        System.out.println(people.get(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's trivial: `System.out.println(people);`

Comment: add overide `toString` to Person class

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter This calls `toString()` which iterates over values.

Comment: @lexicore: yes you are right -- it does so behind the scenes. 1+ to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can print one by one without using loop
>    but the problem is because you are using object type so you cannot print objects unless you use a toString method in the class 
>   even if you don’t use Arraylist it wont work if you want to print object, unless you use toString method

```
    class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {  
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            arrayList.add(6);
            arrayList.add(3);
            arrayList.add(5);

            System.out.println(arrayList.get(0));
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(1));
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(2));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you define "loop". It can be done using a recursive method:

```
void print( ArrayList<Person> a, int index ) {
   if ( (a != null) && (index < a.size()) ) {
      System.out.println(a.get(index));
      print( a, ++index );
   }
}
```

then call print( people, 0 );

Comment: One plus for cleverness

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

Every approach will loop over the values of the array list in certain form. Be it a normal `for` loop or `forEach` or the built-in `toString()` - every approach will loop or iterate over the values of the list in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Probably have to get the object call tostring method to print the data otherwise you will get the object reference

Comment: `toString` effectively iterates over values of the list.

Answer (score 0):

`people.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person));`

The above one-liner uses the stream-functionality introduced in Java-8. Conceptually, you're still iterating through the input-elements one by one. But it's more concise than using a for-loop, if that's what you're looking for.